# Sorting 5 generated numbers from lowest to highest

Tags: java, swing, sorting

I have a project in school to make a simplified Yatzy program and now I've hit a road bump. I have generated 5 random dice throws and printed them out in one window, but I need to sort them from lowest to highest and I don't know how.
I've looked in forums like this one but I don't understand, feel free to ask questions if you don't understand. BTW I'm Swedish so the text in the "" lines are in Swedish if you don't understand.
This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Projekt1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Välkommen till Johans Yatzy");
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Vill du starta spelet?");


    int[] tar = new int[5];

    String output = "";
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    tar[i] = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
    output = output + tar[i] + "\t";
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dina tärningskast blev följande: " + output);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
java.util.Arrays.sort(tar);
```

to sort the int array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tar.length; i++){
    tar[i] = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
}

// sort tar array
java.util.Arrays.sort(tar);

for (int i = 0; i < tar.length; i++) {
    output = output + tar[i] + "\t";
}
```

Comment: Where do i put, java.util.Arrays.sort(tar); in the code? I still get the same result.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now :)